# Am I using "back up" and "back over" correctly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Can I use “back up” and “back over” in those ways?

> 1. Does get “**back over the line**” mean “get **back in** line”?
> 2. Could “**back over here**” mean “**come over** here”?
> 3. Can “**backup**” mean “**standup**”?

Suppose a person just sat down in a classroom. When a Teacher tells the student "Get back up" it means "Stand back up", true? Or maybe they use *up* only when you are not done standing?

I saw a person in a movie one time saying:

> I bring backups in case we need any.
>   or
>   I'll put some backups in case you need them.

Is *backup* used in that sentence the same way you say “backup your files” or is it informal?

Can I say: I'm always running out of water when I travel, get a backup bottle so we don't run out.

Are the sentences above, correct?

Comment: Jacob, you have not provided any sample sentences. Also, when referring to expressions, it is a good idea to use **bolding** or "quotation marks". For example: Can **back up** mean **stand up** if the person just sat down? Also,please check your spelling before posting. Thank you.

Comment: @Lambie  Yes, I don't understand what *If the person just sat down.* refers to either. I think the OP is confusing back with standing? e.g. "Sit with your back straight"? "Get back up on your feet"? "Don't turn your back on me"? All wild guesses of course.

Comment: @Jacob - Stop asking follow-on questions in comments. Edit your question instead. Better yet, spend a little time double-checking your question before you submit it, and make sure you've asked everything you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get back over the line!** means that  you should step across the line to the other side.  The line marks a boundary of some kind. The speaker is telling you that you are on the wrong side of the boundary.

**Get back over here!** is said when the speaker wants you to return to where the speaker is. You have gone to another location and the speaker is telling you to return.

You can use those phrases in the declarative voice too:

> I am going to get back over the line.
>
> I am going to get back over there.

Notice that you would say *there* when someone has said "Get back over *here*!"

> I want you to get back over here!
>   --OK, I will be there in a moment.

The words **here** and **there** are *deictic*, expressing a particular point-of-view.

Comment: in line I meant a waiting line

Comment: @Jacob: That makes no difference.  The line was presented as a boundary, if you have reported correctly what was said.   Now, if the words had been **Get back *into* (the) line**, the meaning would be different.

Comment: Okay, but is it the same as fall in line or is more like spoken only?

Comment: No, it is not the same.  "Fall in line" is not at all the same thing as "Get back over the line".   They both use the word "line" but, that's all that is similar about them.